# What is the remainder of $31^{2008}$ divided by $36$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, totient-function

What is the remainder of $31^{2008}$ divided by $36$?

Using [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), we have:

$$
\begin{align*}
\gcd(31,36) = 1 &\implies 31^{35} \equiv 1 \pmod{36} \\
&\implies 31^{2008} \equiv 31^{35(57) + 13} \equiv (31^{35})^{57+13} \equiv 1^{57}*31^{13} \\
&\implies 31^{13} \equiv 31\pmod{36}
\end{align*}
$$

So the remainder is $31$, is this correct?

Comment: $31^{\phi(36)} \equiv 1 \pmod {36}$

Comment: You're trying to use Fermat's Little Theorem but that only holds if the modulus is a prime number.

Comment: $a^{\phi (n)} \equiv 1 \left(mod \, \, n\right)$ is Euler's theorem if $n \perp a$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Euler's Theorem states $a^{\phi (n)} \equiv 1 \left(\mod \, \, n\right)$ if $a \perp n$, or $\gcd(a,n)=1$. Since $\gcd(31,36)=1$,

\begin{equation}
31^{\phi (36)} = 31^{12} \equiv 1 (\mod\,\,36)
\end{equation}

Then,

\begin{align}
(31^{12})^2 &= 31^{144} \equiv 1 (\mod \, \, 36) \\
31^{144} \cdot (31^{12})^{155}  &= 31^{2004} \equiv 1 (\mod \, \, 36)
\end{align}

So,

\begin{equation}
31^{2008} = 31^{2004} \cdot 31^4 \equiv 1 \cdot 31^4 (\mod \, \, 36)
\end{equation}

But $31 \equiv 31 (\mod \, \, 36) \equiv -5 (\mod \, \, 36)$ so

\begin{equation}
31^2 \equiv (-5)^2 (\mod \, \, 36) \equiv 25 (\mod \, \, 36) \equiv -11 (\mod \, \, 36)
\end{equation}

and then,

\begin{equation}
31^4 \equiv (-11)^2 (\mod \, \, 36) \equiv 121 (\mod \, \, 36) \equiv 13 (\mod \, \, 36)
\end{equation}

Thus,

\begin{equation}
31^{2008} \equiv 1 \cdot 31^4 (\mod \, \, 36) \equiv 13 (\mod \, \, 36)
\end{equation}

Comment: Could you please explain how you calculated $\phi (36) = 12$?

Comment: $\phi (36)$ is the number of integers that are less than $36$ and that are coprime, or relatively prime, to $36$. Using a nice shortcut, write the prime factorization of $36$, or $36 = 2^2 \cdot 3^2$. Then

\begin{equation}
\phi (36) = \phi (2^2 \cdot 3^2) = \phi (2^2) \cdot \phi (3^2) = (2^2 - 2^1) \cdot (3^2 - 3^1) = (4 - 2) \cdot (9 - 3) = 2 \cdot 6 = 12
\end{equation}

Comment: Euler's totient function $\phi$ is multiplicative if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, namely

\begin{equation}
\phi (m \cdot n) = \phi (m) \cdot \phi (n)
\end{equation}

Also, for a prime $p$

\begin{equation}
\phi (p^k) = p^k - p^{k-1}
\end{equation}

where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

The line that goes $31^{35}\equiv 1 \pmod {36}$ is false. Euler's theorem says that $31^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod {36}$, but $\phi(36) = 12$. So we would say $31^{2008} \equiv 31^{4} \pmod{36}$ using the same reduction method (taking away multiples of 12) to get $13 \pmod{36}$.

Comment: How did you calculate $\phi(36) = 12$.. also how did you calculate $31^{2008} \equiv 31^{4} \pmod{36}$? Could you please break this down step-by-step? You can use other examples if you like.